# C# What am I doing wrong? Attempting counter up with do while loop but only iterating once

Tags: c#

Help, I'm a novice programming student who got assigned a side task at work; This is the pseudo code I wrote for it:

Write a program with 3 buttons:

- Exit/Close, Clear/Reset, Count/Calculate
- When the user clicks the count button, the number displayed in the label/textbox should increase by 1 and this should continue infinitely.
- When the user clicks the clear/Reset button, the number displayed in the label/textbox should be reset to 0.`{
          Application.Exit();
      }

  ```
  private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      int Count = 1;
      int Numberdisplayed; 

      {
          do Count++;

          while (Count >= 1);

          Numberdisplayed = Count + 1;

          lblNumberdisplayed.Text = Numberdisplayed.ToString();

      }

  }

  private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int Count = 0;
      lblNumberdisplayed.Text = String.Empty;
      lblNumberdisplayed.Text = Count.ToString();

  }
  ```

  }
  `
- When the user clicks the Exit/Close btn, the application should close.

The only language I am familiar with is c# hence my writing it here and my company runs windows for all end users so I figured why not. 
  private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

[The code I have so far Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJx27.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't bound to use `While` loop you can try using session or the below:

```
private int count;
protected void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    count =   Int32.Parse(lblCount.Text);
    count++; 
    lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
 }
```

**Note**: Though not tested, you can try the above.

Comment: Why adding state when the textbox is anyway authoritive?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the Count variable is local to the method, thus the do while never sees the reset.